# Fixed nav bar won't scroll right with rest of page

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, navbar

I found some code I wanted to use to make a static navigation bar that stays at the top of the screen as you scroll down.  That part worked out fine.

However, when I resize the browser window, at first it would wrap to the next line.  So I added white-space:nowrap so it would stay on one line.  But now, if I resize the window, it will just cut off the navbar at the edge of the browser window.

I would like the page to scroll right/left, not just scrollbars under the navbar.  How might I do that?

Thank you in advance.  This is what I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/TYgSx/14/embedded/result/

This is the HTML (edited to add page content):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul id="navigation">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non elit turpis. Nulla non dolor non magna pellentesque iaculis a vel dolor. Nunc vel est elementum, faucibus magna ut, iaculis tellus. Praesent euismod pharetra mauris non adipiscing. Proin venenatis nunc id neque tincidunt, sit amet consectetur sapien pellentesque. Morbi sit amet tincidunt odio, eget rhoncus velit. Proin mollis luctus molestie. Suspendisse facilisis ligula sed posuere dapibus. Integer mauris risus, bibendum a lacus vel, sollicitudin varius lacus. Maecenas vitae pharetra quam, quis blandit tortor. Cras adipiscing laoreet pulvinar. Ut lacus erat, lobortis vel auctor id, ullamcorper quis nisi. In tempor lacus non urna mattis, sed suscipit nisi varius. Aliquam at turpis in justo pellentesque lacinia in vitae odio.</p>

<p>Integer fringilla eros quis risus rhoncus tempus. Nunc aliquet magna blandit turpis suscipit lacinia. Aenean laoreet varius velit a aliquam. Proin tincidunt dolor et velit egestas semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pretium sodales ornare. Sed at tellus sit amet libero imperdiet dapibus. Fusce ultricies enim sit amet neque sodales porttitor.</p>

<p>Duis dignissim massa id ultrices consequat. Phasellus libero est, posuere quis orci non, lobortis sodales nisl. Maecenas fermentum, nisl at elementum lobortis, nisi dui dictum risus, pharetra aliquet ante elit non justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec porttitor pellentesque libero id volutpat. Aenean tempus sapien nunc, quis hendrerit lectus gravida volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque posuere diam in pulvinar ultrices.</p>

<p>Donec vitae diam erat. Aenean volutpat fringilla hendrerit. Sed quis ornare erat. Vivamus sit amet augue lacinia, rhoncus erat a, ultrices eros. Proin eget facilisis tellus. Sed eleifend porttitor orci vitae aliquet. Aliquam aliquam tristique nisl vitae laoreet. Morbi ac luctus ipsum, a molestie nulla. Vivamus at erat at dui fermentum vestibulum. Pellentesque vulputate in lacus eget ultrices. In imperdiet nisl non vehicula congue. Maecenas mattis semper enim. Duis consectetur sapien ac enim pellentesque mattis. Phasellus molestie vitae ipsum nec facilisis.</p>

<p>Integer lobortis a felis non pellentesque. In sit amet sagittis lacus, vel aliquam urna. Phasellus sodales erat quis ante aliquam interdum. Ut vitae dolor diam. Nullam nisi felis, euismod ac nunc eget, fringilla pretium nisi. Proin commodo vestibulum elit eget luctus. Pellentesque nisi felis, congue in sem in, elementum ultricies metus. Vivamus mollis nisi non ante imperdiet, nec posuere dui aliquam. Ut rhoncus risus in malesuada accumsan. In vestibulum auctor diam, sit amet vestibulum mauris. Praesent eu nibh lorem. Suspendisse turpis libero, sollicitudin vitae lacinia et, volutpat et tortor. Aliquam vitae ultrices ante. Ut commodo vitae est sit amet bibendum.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS (added top-margin of 80px to page content):

```
#nav
 {
 background-color:#262626;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 50px #5E5E5E;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 white-space:nowrap;
}

#navigation
{
 list-style-type:none; 
}
li 
{
 display:inline;
 padding:10px;
}

#nav a
{
 font-family:verdana;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#EDEDED;
} 
#nav a:hover 
{
 color:#BDBDBD;
}
h1
{
margin-top:80px;
}
body
{
min-width:800px
}
```

Comment: I added content to the html so the example would be more obvious.  Now, when the page is resized horizontally to less than 800px, the page (content, text, etc) will have a scroll bar but at a certain point, the fixed header just gets cut off.  Any tips on getting the header to scroll with the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add overflow and set it to auto in your css.

```
#nav {
 background-color:#262626;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 50px #5E5E5E;
 position:fixed;
 **overflow: auto;**
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried that, but it only adds scroll bars (horizontal and vertical) to the div itself.  I'm looking for a solution that will add a scroll bar (horizontal only) at the bottom of the browser window so it will scroll right/left with the rest of the page's content.

Comment: @user2488073 With what you have provided that's all there is to work with. It would be beneficial to provide the HTML/CSS for one full page so that the issue can be more appropriately determined as a whole.

Comment: I'm updating the page with content to better illustrate what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific to the overflow that you want to scroll, in this case you want overflow-y:auto;